# Widget code that allows for javascript event callbacks

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a web application for submitting polls and whatnot. I have developed some widget code that, when a `<div class = "desiredClass">` is present, a poll is fetched from the database via `ajax` request and is put into the html and users can vote on the poll.

so for my widget.js file that gets embedded into the html as a script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($('.loadPoll')[0]) {


    var name = $('.loadPoll').data("pollname");
    var IP_Address = '-1';
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://url.com:3000/loadPoll',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
        pollName: name
      },
      success: function (data) {
        poll = data.poll;
        $(".loadPoll").html(data.html);
        $(document).on('click', '#SubmitVote', function () {
          var selectedValue;
          var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
          for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            if (radios[i].type === 'radio' && radios[i].checked) {
              selectedValue = radios[i].value;
            }
          }
          console.log(selectedValue);
          $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?", function (data) {
            var IP_Address = data.ip;

            $.ajax({
              url: 'http://url.com:3000/submitVote',
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              data: {
                pollName: poll.pollName,
                voterID: IP_Address,
                vote: selectedValue
              },
              success: callback("Vote successful")

            });
          });
        });
      }
    });
  })
```

This basically sends a request to the server, html is returned, then, when `#SubmitVote` is 
clicked the value of the radio button is sent to the server as a vote.

I want to be able to "allow for javascript event callbacks". Pseudocode example:

```
Poll.onSubmit(function() {
        console.log('hello world');
    });
```

How would one do this?

Comment: Assuming you have a poll function you'd add an onSubmit function to it that takes one parameter. Inside onSubmit you'd call it

Comment: @AndrewWalters I'm not familiar with how to do just that. Would I create a poll object client-side and add various methods to it? Or are you suggesting using straight up functions? Thanks for your reply

Comment: Sorry if I'm not making sense. I just don't really understand what's being asked of me. How would I be able to use dot notation on poll? I think that's what I need to know.

Comment: I'll write up an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the dot notation like you have there you'd want a function called `Poll` in your javascript.

```
function Poll()
{
    var self = this;
    //various things poll's do

    self.onSubmit = function(callback)
    {
        //Submit Code

        if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {  
              callback();  
       }  

    }
```

}

Then somewhere make a new `Poll` object.

```
var poll = new Poll();
```

Then you could call onSubmit and pass a callback.

```
poll.onSubmit(function() {
        console.log('hello world');
    });
```

Comment: Ahah! Excellent write up I get it now. Thanks, Andrew.